# How to make Composables containing Android View respect zIndex when placed inside a Box Layout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer

I am trying to stack Composables that contain AndroidView. However they seem to not respect the zIndex in a Box Layout. The newest composable associated  with lowest zIndex always renders at the top even though it should be at the bottom.

The idea is to render two videos stacked on top of each other.For eg lets say videos with ids [4, 5]. At first video on top [5] is visible. On pressing the button , this video is removed from movieList and last 2 videos [3,4] are passed to ContentList . Now instead of seeing video [4] on top, somehow video [3] is visible at the top of Box. I have verified that the rendering sequence is correct, yet somehow i see preview for video [3] on top.

Here's the code

```
var movieList = remember { mutableStateListOf(mock4.get(0), mock4.get(1), mock4.get(2), mock4.get(3), mock4.get(4), mock4.get(5),) }

fun onClick() {
  movieList.removeLast()
}

Column {
  // I only pass the last two elements from the above list to be rendered
  ContentList(movieList.takeLast(2))

// Clicking the button removes the last element from the list
  Button( onClick = ::onClick) {
    Text(text = "remove last")
  }
}

@Composable
private fun ContentList(movieList: List<GameEntry>) {
  Box {
    LogCompositions(tag = "", msg = "ContentList Box ")
      movieList.forEachIndexed { index, movie ->
       // I do not want to rerender composables based on the id field, which is unique
        key(movie.id) {
          ContentView(
            Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), movie, index == 1
          )
        }
      }
  }
}

@Composable
private fun ContentView(modifier: Modifier, movie: GameEntry, isActive: Boolean) {
  Card(
    modifier
      .height(400.dp)
      .padding(horizontal = 30.dp)
  ) {
    MediaPlayer(videoUri = movie.media?.url.toString(), id = movie.id, isActive)
    
// The below text Composable works as expected but the ^^ Media player does not
    Text(
      text = movie.id.toString(),
      textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
      modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
  }
  DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    onDispose {
      Log.e("", "Disposed Card id -> ${movie.id}")
    }
  }
}
@Composable
fun MediaPlayer(videoUri: String, id: Long, isActive:Boolean) {
  val exoPlayer = remember {... }

  DisposableEffect(
    AndroidView(
      factory = {
        PlayerView(context).apply {
          hideController()
          useController = false
          resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM
          player = exoPlayer
          layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
          )
        }
      },
    )
  ) {
    onDispose {
      exoPlayer.release()
    }
  }
}
```